# JUnit Test Failure

Tags: java, eclipse, junit

I am trying to run a test on the class below:

package chapter03.backend;

```
import java.util.Map;

public class CharacterCounter {
    public static Map<Character, Integer> countCharacters(String text) {

         if (text == null) {
              throw new IllegalArgumentException("text must not be null");
            }
        return null;

    }
}
```

I have written this test class:

```
package chapter03.backend;

import static org.junit.Assert.*;

import org.junit.Test;

public class CharacterCounterTests {

    @Test(expected=IllegalAccessException.class)
    public void testNullInput() {
        CharacterCounter.countCharacters(null);
    }

}
```

When I run it, it keeps failing. Here is a screen shot of the error:

[image]

I will appreciate pointers on this.

Answer (score 2):

`IllegalAccessException` is not `IllegalArgumentException` and is not a subclass of it either.

You throw indeed `IllegalArgumentException` in your tested method but you assert in the test that `IllegalArgumentException` is thrown.
Consequently, the assertion fails.

You should assert that `IllegalArgumentException` is expected:

```
@Test(expected=IllegalArgumentException.class)
public void testNullInput() {
    CharacterCounter.countCharacters(null);
}
```

Comment: Very very probably. Sometimes a copy paste is not so bad ;-)

Comment: It is a copy and paste! I apologize but a Java nubian. Not sure I understand the difference between what you pasted and what I have there

Comment: `@Test(expected=IllegalAccessException.class)` means that you expect that a IllegalArgumentException is thrown during the test method execution. But you never throw it in the tested code. You throw that : `throw new IllegalArgumentException("text must not be null")`. So Junit says you that your expected was not matched.